# Matlab, How to use repelem (available in Matlab 2015) for a matrix (mxn) in Matlab 2014

Tags: matlab

I want to repeat each element of 3x3 matrix to make it 9x9. There is a direct function repelem in Matlab2015, but i am using older version.

How to perform this task manually?

Comment: repmat will repeat the entire matrix, but here i want to repeat each element of matrix.

Comment: Thanks for encouragement. I am trying this. Here i need to put repmat output  for each element in a loop to get desired matrix.

Comment: Kindly help me in loop formation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [kron(A,B)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function. It was introduced before R2006a so you should have it in R2014. This function calculates the [Kronecker Tensor Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). It multiplies each element of matrix A with the full matrix B and thus creating a bigger matrix.
For example,

```
>> A = magic(3)

A =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> B = ones(3)

B =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

>> C = kron(A,B)

C =

     8     8     8     1     1     1     6     6     6
     8     8     8     1     1     1     6     6     6
     8     8     8     1     1     1     6     6     6
     3     3     3     5     5     5     7     7     7
     3     3     3     5     5     5     7     7     7
     3     3     3     5     5     5     7     7     7
     4     4     4     9     9     9     2     2     2
     4     4     4     9     9     9     2     2     2
     4     4     4     9     9     9     2     2     2
```